# mypy seems to think that (*args, **kwargs) could match to any funtion signature?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, typing, liskov-substitution-principle

How does mypy apply the Liskov substitution principle to `*args, **kwargs` parameters?

I thought the following code should fail a mypy check since some calls to `f` allowed by the `Base` class are not allowed by `C`, but it actually passed. Are there any reasons for this?

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any


class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> int:
        pass


class C(Base):
    def f(self, batch: int, train: bool) -> int:
        return 1
```

I also tried to remove either `*args` or `**kwargs`, both failed.

Comment: I imagine the authors of mypy just took the pragmatic approach rather than the strict approach since `*args: Any, **kwargs: Any` is typically used to mean "untyped" rather than "actually has this signature"

Comment: and yes, I think this does violate LSP

Comment: Imagine a list with static type `list[Base]`. With such a list, `list[0].f(1,2,3,4,5,)` should be legal, but it's not if `list[0]` is an instance of `C`. `mypy` does not seem to take type hints on an abstract method into account. (With the decoration, for example, `mypy` will rightly complain that `f` does not return an `int`.)

Comment: (without the decoration, that is.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike [Daniil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75138375/14401160) said in currently accepted answer, the reason is exactly `(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any)` signature part.

Please check the [corresponding discussion on `mypy` issue tracker](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5876):

> I actually like this idea, I have seen this confusion several times, and although it is a bit unsafe, most of the time when people write (*args, **kwargs) it means "don't care", rather than "should work for all calls".

> [GVR] Agreed, this is a case where practicality beats purity.

So, `mypy` gives a special treatment to functions of form

```py
# _T is arbitrary type
class _:
    def _(self, *args, **kwargs) -> _T: ...
```

and considers them fully equivalent to `Callable[..., _T]`.

Yes, this actually violates LSP, of course, but this was designed specially to allow declaring functions with signature "just ignore my parameters".

To declare the broadest possible function that really accepts arbitrary positional and keyword arguments, you should use `object` in signature instead.

Comment: To be fair, I said "it has nothing to with `*args` or `**kwargs` _per se_" and that is correct. Using them with any other annotation would cause an error. They only _don't_ cause an error, if you use them together with `Any`. I concede that I was not very clear in the follow up because it made it seem as though `args`/`kwargs` had _nothing at all_ to do with it, which is of course not the case. But your explanation is better because it links the exact issue for that question.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `*args` or `**kwargs` per se. The reason for this is strictly the fact that you used [`typing.Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any) for both annotations.

The `Any` annotation is basically a **Jedi mind trick** for the type checker to the effect of:

> These **are** the types you were looking for.

No matter what, it will always pass.

For this reason, the `typing` documentation [specifically recommends](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/best_practices.html#using-any-and-object) to use `object` as much as possible instead of `Any`, when you mean to say something like *"the broadest possible type"*. `Any` should be reserved as the last resort, when you bump against the limits of the Python typing system.

The `mypy` docs also have a [section](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dynamic_typing.html?highlight=any#any-vs-object) explaining the difference between `Any` and `object`.

If you change even one of those `Any` annotations to `object`, you will be rightfully chastised by `mypy` with an `[override]` error for `C.f`.

Example:

```py
from typing import Any

class Base:
    def f(self, *args: object, **kwargs: Any) -> int:
        return 2

class C(Base):
    def f(self, batch: int, train: bool) -> int:  # now this is an error
        return 1
```

Whereas the combination of saying *"any number of positional and keyword-arguments"* together with *"each argument will always pass the type check"* essentially translates to *"no override will ever be wrong"* (in terms of arguments).

So I would suggest using `object` instead of `Any` **everywhere**, unless you cannot avoid using the latter.

These confusions are one of the reasons I think the choice to name this construct **`Any`** is so unfortunate.

### PS

My first paragraph was not well worded. As [@SUTerliakov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149156/19770795) explained more clearly, the reason this override does not cause an error is specifically because of the **combination** of the `*args`/`**kwargs` parameters and them being annotated with `Any`. Only if both conditions are met, does `mypy` make this exception.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that `Any` is the broadest type. What I am confused about is that according to LSP, method of child class should accept _any_ signature accepted by that of base class, so since `Any` is broader than `object`, the set of methods that satisfy signature `*args: Any, **kwargs: Any` should be a subset of  `*args: object, **kwargs: object`. What ever passed by the former should also be passed by the later.

Comment: @ppc It seems like you didn't read what I wrote at all... It is **not** the broadest possible type. It technically isn't even a type at all. It disengages the type checker. `object` is the broadest possible type.